# XMLSchema and XMLSchema-instance namespaces without schemaLocation

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have few questions about xml namespace, I will explain with these three pieces of code:

**1 - Very simple XML Schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.library.com"
        targetNamespace="http://www.library.com"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<element name="Book" type="tns:BookType" />

<complexType name="BookType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Title" type="string" />
    <element name="Author" type="string" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>

</schema>
```

**2 - XML that use the newly created xml schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.wc3.org/2001XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.library.com ex9.xsd"
            xmlns="http://www.library.com">

   <Title>Scherlock Holmes</Title>
   Author>Arthur Conan Doyle</Author>
</Book>
```

**3 - Another fragment code without relationship from the two above:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
    ....
    </beans>
```

### Question are:

1. Why always are we declare namespaces like
   **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** and **xmlns:xsi="http://www.wc3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** but no **schemaLocation** for these is given?
2. How an XML parser will know (for example for to validate) that
   **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** define elements like `<attribute>`, `<complexType>`, `<sequence>`, etc?
3. Reading many posts I understood that namespaces and thus their URI,
   means basically nothing, they are used just for avoid name
   conflicting. But I read also that if you declare
   **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** namespace wrong the XML file will not valid, why?
4. Why In the last code fragment always no schemaLocation is given for
   **http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Those built-in namespaces pertain to XSD components themselves.  No
   `schemaLocation` is necessary because their definition is implied by
   the XML Schema Recommendation.
2. A conformant XML parser by definition will understand the meaning of
   `xs:attribute`, etc.
3. I wouldn't say that namespaces mean nothing.  Beyond being a way of
   differentiating otherwise identifically named components, namespaces
   can also be used to associate the use of components with their
   collective definition in another XSD.
4. As stated in #1, `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` is a
   built-in namespace consisting of components whose definitions are
   already implied by the XML Schema Recommendation.